# import module package not exist

Tags: java, android, module

I have imported a module (squarecamera) but I have this error whin

```
Error:(26, 32) error: package com.desmond.squarecamera does not exist
```

this is the code :

```
import com.desmond.squarecamera.CameraActivity;
...
public void launchCamera() {
    Intent startCustomCameraIntent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(startCustomCameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can I fix this error